# Can I make Amazon SageMaker deliver a recommendation based on historic data instead of a probability score?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

We have a huge set of data in CSV format, containing a few numeric elements, like this:

```
Year,BinaryDigit,NumberToPredict,JustANumber, ...other stuff
1954,1,762,16, ...other stuff
1965,0,142,16, ...other stuff
1977,1,172,16, ...other stuff
```

The thing here is that there is a strong correlation between the third column and the columns before that. So I have pre-processed the data and it's now available in a format I think is perfect:

```
1954,1,762
1965,0,142
1977,1,172
```

What I want is a predicition on the value in the third column, using the first two as input. So in the case above, I want the input 1965,0 to return 142. In real life this file is thousands of rows, but since there's a pattern, I'd like to retrieve the most possible value.

So far I've setup a train job on the CSV file using the L*inear Learner* algorithm, with the following settings:

```
label_size = 1
feature_dim = 2
predictor_type = regression
```

I've also created a model from it, and setup an endpoint. When I invoke it, I get a score in return.

```
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                   ContentType='text/csv',
                                   Body=payload)
```

My goal here is to get the third column prediction instead. How can I achieve that? I have read a lot of the documentation regarding this, but since I'm not very familiar with AWS, I might as well have used the wrong algorithms for what I am trying to do.

(Please feel free to edit this question to better suit AWS terminology)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For csv input, the label should be in the first column, as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/cdf-training.html):  So you should preprocess your data to put the label (the column you want to predict) on the left.

Next, you need to decide whether this is a regression problem or a classification problem.

If you want to predict a number that's as close as possible to the true number, that's regression. For example, the truth might be 4, and the model might predict 4.15. If you need an integer prediction, you could round the model's output.

If you want the prediction to be one of a few categories, then you have a classification problem. For example, we might encode 'North America' = 0, 'Europe' = 1, 'Africa' = 2, and so on. In this case, a fractional prediction wouldn't make sense.

For regression, use `'predictor_type' = 'regressor'` and for classification with more than 2 classes, use `'predictor_type' = 'multiclass_classifier'` as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ll_hyperparameters.html).

The output of regression will contain only a `'score'` field, which is the model's prediction. The output of multiclass classification will contain a `'predicted_label'` field, which is the model's prediction, as well as a `'score'` field, which is a vector of probabilities representing the model's confidence. The index with the highest probability will be the one that's predicted as the `'predicted_label'`. The output formats are documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/LL-in-formats.html).

Comment: I switch the answer to this one, since this is way more detailed. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @philipgautier and @macmuffin, Do we set `predictor_type` in `invoke_endpoint` to get the score and predicted label? My endpoint `ContentType` is a `text/csv` for a binary problem, but the response contains just the score for each data instance. How can I get the score and label when doing the inference? tkx guys.

Comment: I set the `predictor_type` in the estimator, but I still getting just the score when calling the `invoke_endpoint`.

Answer (score 0):

`predictor_type = regression` is not able to return the predicted label, according to

[the linear-learner documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/linear-learner.html):

> For inference, the linear learner algorithm supports the application/json, application/x-recordio-protobuf, and text/csv formats. For binary classification models, it returns both the score and the predicted label. For regression, it returns only the score.
>
> For more information on input and output file formats, see [Linear
>   Learner Response Formats](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/LL-in-formats.html) for inference, and the [Linear Learner Sample
>   Notebooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/linear-learner.html#ll-sample-notebooks).